# How to use register of react-hook-form with ValidatedInput of react-jhipster

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, react-hook-form

I have a special Form with many SubForms so I can't use `ValidatedForm` in `react-jhipster`. However, I still want to use `ValidatedInput.

I have a function component contain:

```
<ValidatedInput
  label={translate('studySpaceApp.question.noiDung')}
  id={`question_noiDung_${defaultValues.id}`}
  data-cy="noidung"
  type="text"
  {...register('noiDung')}
  onChange={onChangeQuestionContent}
  validate={{
    required: true,
    minLength: { value: 6, message: translate('entity.validation.minlength', { min: 6 }) },
    maxLength: { value: 255, message: translate('entity.validation.maxlength', { max: 255 }) },
  }}
  defaultValue={questionContent}
/>
```

But react warning: *Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?*

How to fix it?
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass ref to functional components, they cannot be directly used but need to have `forwardRef` in place like this.

```
const ValidatedInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  // Your ValidatedInput body
));
```

And then `<ValidatedInput ref={yourref} {...otherprops} />` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, yeah...
I tried to read source code of `react-jhipster` and i saw the them use a props called `register` that i can pass my `register` (`const { register } = useForm()`). And then, this component handle everything else